# the second "if" statement describes an error if tokens = less than 10. Why is it an error over 10?

Tags: php, mysql

So this php i have here is an update mysql query stating that if tokens < 10 echo "some error".. problem is that every time i execute the code it returns the error. in the same way every time even if tokens = 11.. I simply don't understand 
FULL CODE

//if not logged in redirect to login page

```
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); exit(); }
```

//define page title

```
$title = 'Dashboard ~ Pixel Jag.';
```

//include header template

```
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "database";
```

// Create connection

```
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

// Check connection

```
if (!$db) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (($_SESSION['tokens'] < 10)) {
echo "<ul class='list-group'><li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>You do not have enough tokens!</li></ul>";
}
else {
$sql = "UPDATE members SET tokens=tokens - 10, tokenstatus='(Pending Tokens)' ,tokenswith=tokenswith + 10, tokenstatus1='(Pending Tokens)' WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username']) ."'";
}
if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
echo "<ul class='list-group'><li class='list-group-item list-group-item-success'><h4>Record updated successfully!</h4></li></ul>";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
}

mysqli_close($db);
?> 

<div class="panel-footer">
<a href="index.php"><h4>Back To Dashboard..</h4></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
```

//include header template

```
require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION['tokens']` actually set?

Comment: if i take the if statement out it just takes 10 out of the users tokens. so i take it it's set? if not how in the world do i get the result i want on this? i

Comment: No, that doesn't mean it's set at all. Try this: `unset $x; echo ($x < 10) ? 'true' : 'false';` and you will see it prints `true`.

Comment: so with the code i have already what would i add to begin a session and call the correct sql query to update only if the user has 10 tokens? sorry i am so baffled lol.

Comment: That's too much for a comment. I suggest you start by reading the PHP manual on [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

It must be because there value in session variable is less than ten. 
Try checking the following things
1. Did you start the session?
2. If yes, the session is started then try to echo the value of session
3. If the session is started and value shows zero go where you are trying to put the session variable value and check if there is some spelling error or some insertion error.

Comment: i would assume it is because i have the config.php included at start followed by //if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); exit(); }

//define page title
$title = 'Dashboard ~ Pixel Jag.';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>

Comment: Can you post the full code then? Because from this code i only can come up to following errors only